# Generate website hierarchy diagram

Tags: sitemap, hierarchy

I have a website that I've been asked to create a hierarchy diagram of. It's a right mess and I'm too lazy to generate one.

Is there a quick online site that could do the job? Or if anyone has any ideas of how to do it quickly. The one requirement is that it needs to be in a hierarchical style.

Comment: Could it be automatically done from a sitemap?

Comment: did you find any solution? I am in the same shoe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apple script to generate Omnigraffle diagram](http://blog.fuzzymath.com/2010/08/05/omnigraffle-sitemap-generator-from-sitemap-xml/)

Generate an XML sitemap first then use the script in the link above. It then automatically creates an Omnigraffle hierarchy, cracking!

Comment: Haha, wouldn't be the first time I've answered my own question!

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for "breadcrumb" + your actually tool... in Google

Comment: I'm using Omnigraffle, ideally I'd like to get it into that.

Answer (score 0):

Power Point / SmartArt Graphic / Hierarchy